# Одноразовое выполнение БД-запросов при нескольких одновременных запросах

Tags: php, mysql

Иногда начали проскакивать одновременные запросы к скрипту, из-за чего запросы к БД начали выполняться несколько раз. Если конкретнее, то есть таблица заказов и скрипт на проверку заказа. Если к нему идут одновременные запросы, то заказ дважды меняет статус на успешный, идет двойной начисление средств за него и двойной учет в статистику.

При чем проверка на статус заказа стоит. "Если заказ созданный, то только тогда всё это выполняем". Но так как обращение идет одновременно, то и заказ будет созданный для всех таких запросов. Пробовал выполнять через транзакции, но тоже не помогло.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: а пример кода ГДЕ?

Comment: наверное проблема в алгоритме ?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9